# images and upload option is not showing in Magento Enterprise 1.14.2.0

Tags: magento

Images and upload options are not showing in backend in Magento Enterprise 1.14.2.0. Please guide, it is not browser or flash issue as i have another magento community version website which is showing both images and upload option from back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied below patches and it start working

SUPEE-5994
SUPEE-6285
SUPEE-6482
SUPEE-6788
SUPEE-7405 v1
SUPEE-7405 v2
SUPEE-8788
SUPEE-9652
SUPEE-9767